# XCode 6.1 Image Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add an Image to an UIImageView, this works fine on the simulator but not on my Device... I am doing this in InterfaceBuilder, just as it is in multiple other ImageViews, but this one is not working...

I tried to disable PNG Compression, checked the "Copy Bundle Resources" Option (my PNG is in there), tried to add it programmatically (causes Exception).
I cleaned the Product multiple times, and tried on different devices with iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.1.
What can I do now?

Comment: It would be worth deleting the image view in interface builder and from being reference by any IBOutlets. Save and close xcode. Reopen xcode and add it back but using different IBOutlet names where referenced. I had an UIImageView once which just would not work on real devices and this was what I had to do. Drove me mad looking for what was wrong. Also what happens if you use a different image in the same code?

Comment: How are you adding the image programmatically?

Comment: name of image bust be same, in device it even check case-senstivity. So make sure about this.

Comment: As @rishi says, this is very likely because you've not got the case right on the image name. The simulator is not case-sensitive but actual devices are.

Comment: I added a UIImageView for testing:
the name of the image is completely in lower case. I can asign it directly in InterfaceBuilder with this name. The image is not showing up on the Device again... Even with new IBOutlet AND with another Image which is asigned on another View (and working)

Comment: while I created another UIImageView I realized something strange:
I deleted the old View but the IBOutlet was still connected to it.
Is it possible that, there is some Cache for Xib Files? And that my Controller on the Device is still working with the Old Xib?

Comment: Ok, its working now. I just created everything new... Thanks!